# Is it possible to getting total/available memory on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How to getting total/available memory on Windows Phone? The total/available memory what I mean is for the whole device, not only for my application itself, can I get them?

Comment: For which purpose do you want to use this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the device's total memory (potentially useful for detecting low memory devices) by using the [DeviceExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class on 7.0 or the [DeviceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class on 7.1.

You can also access the amount of memory your app is currently using and the most it has used, but there is no way to find the available memory for the device.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can only access the memory of its isolated storage and cannot interrupt with other applications. This is a constraint but have to cope with it.